# Change gem env RUBY EXECUTABLE path for one command

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems

I would like to run gem commands, such as `gem install`, with a different ruby version than what is listed in `gem env`. The Ruby version I want to use is a pre-compiled version which I have the path for, so installing and using another version from RVM or similar would not solve my problem.

I do not want to change the `RUBY EXECUTABLE` permanently, just for one command at a time. I have tried to set `GEM_HOME`, `GEM_PATH`, `PATH`, `RUBY` and more. I have tried firing up gem with `specific/version/of/ruby/path/ruby path/to/gem env`, but I still get the default Ruby in my `RUBY EXECUTABLE` variable.

I even tried setting`RUBY_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/correct/ruby`, which also did not work.

What really surprised me was that when I edited the shebang in the `path/to/gem` file itself so it pointed to the correct Ruby, it still did not work! What is up with that?!

How can I change this variable so I can use gem goodness with my custom compiled Ruby?

---

This one is really beating me. I have now updated my `rbconfig.rb` to point to the desired Ruby path. I have looked at the rubygems source and replaced every single instance of the default ruby , in all the files I could find,  with the path to the one I want. Even this did not set the environment correctly. Is this somehow hard-coded into the compiled ruby? If that is the case, why the star*4 is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of research, stepping through the Ruby source with Pry, reading source code and more I figured out that this is not possible to do because it is hard-coded into ruby at compile time (wtf?). Anyway, the way to solve this is to simply `recompile Ruby`. Yeah.

There is also apparently a compile flag which you can set which removes this hard-coded environment: `--enable-load-relative`

After struggling with this for way to long I finally got [this project working](https://github.com/stephan-nordnes-eriksen/ruby_ship), where I have made an easy to use portable version of Ruby. Simply put, a folder with Ruby on it which you can move about, put on a USB stick or whatever, and it still works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using rbenv (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or RVM to manage Ruby versions (https://rvm.io/).  When you switch Ruby versions with rbenv, gem env will use use the new Ruby version.  The following command can be used to change the Ruby version for a single shell:

```
$ rbenv shell 2.1.2
```

Comment: This seem to be a nice solution, but I need to use a special version of ruby which I have the path for, and not one that is provided by rbenv or rvm, so I can't use this. What I truly need is to change the RUBY EXECUTABLE path for the gems command, not install and use another ruby version. Thanks for the tip though! I bet it is very useful in other contexts!